# Javascript: Записать значение в DOM

Tags: javascript

Есть два блока:

```
  <div class="myclass">1</div>
  <div class="myclass">2</div>
```

Для блока 1 я сгенерировал число, предположим '111', а для блока 2 - '222'.
Я хотел бы присвоить этим блокам идентификаторы, исходя из сгенерированных цифр. Но, чтобы они не отображались на странице типа: `<div class="myclass" data-myid="111">1</div>`.

Хочется скрыть эти идентификаторы в DOM дереве. И в определенный момент найти, обратиться к ним по сгенерированным числам '111' и '222', чтобы перенести/ клонировать/удалить соответствующий блок.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать? Желательно только на Javascript без jQuery.

Comment: Какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить сокрытием идентификаторов в DOM? [XY-проблема](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/)

Comment: А что значит генерировать число? Это случайное число или нет? Почему играет роль момент его генерации? И почему нельзя сгенерировать `data-myid` в нужный для вас момент и по ним обратиться?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, что непонятного? Ему нужно присвоить блоку уникальный идентификатор, который не будет видно в HTML, но он сможет обратится к элементу с помощью этого идентификатора

Comment: @Yuri Я хочу услышать лично от отвечающего его версию.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, Генерировать число, значит генерировать случайное число с помощью встроенной функции Javascript. Роль генерации играет такую, что оно должно быть уникальным для каждого блока, чтобы была возможность отличать их руг от друга. data-myid не хочу, чтобы появлялось в HTML.

Comment: По моему, это не возможно.

Comment: @AK, я пытаюсь сделать прелоадер для плагина загрузки фото с помощью ajax. При отправке на сервер нескольких картинок нужно добавить соответсвующее количетсво прелоадеров. После удачного ответа от сервера загрузки файлов на сервер эти прелоадеры нужно удалить и на их место показать загруженную миниатюру картинки. Для того, чтобы отличить прелоадер я присвою ему идентификатор. А когда придет ответ от сервера я по идентификатору определю определенный блок прелоадера и удалю его

Comment: @Pavel вопрос: зачем скрывать идентификаторы?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, конечно, будет работать с data атрибутами, присвоив ему data-id. Но хотел бы альтернативный вариант.

Comment: @Pavel  просто никто не понимает зачем это скрывать? В чем смысл, идея такого поведения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Функция, генерирующая случайное число
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

// Здесь будем хранить ссылки на все найденные элементы
var mapElements = {}
// В вашем случае, получаем все элементы по имени класса:
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')
// Перебираем все найденные элементы
for (var i = 0, l = elements.length, i < l; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    // добавляем поле dataMyId к каждому элементу и присваиваем ему случайный идентификатор
    // Это поле, естественно не отобразится в HTML
    element.dataMyId = getRandom(100, 900);
    mapElements[element.dataMyId] = element;
}
```

Потом, для того, чтобы использовать найденные элементы мы можем доставать их по идентификатору из `mapElements`

Comment: как это все скрывает идентификаторы в DOM?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так оно и не скрывает, оно просто не добавляет. Ведь `dataMyId` элемента в DOM не попадает.

Comment: Правильней бы было сказать не имеет отображения в HTML

Comment: только генерация не совсем корректная.. может сгенерироваться одно и то же число несколько раз, не смотря на разброс...... нужно проверять/или хранить сгенерированные числа, чтоб при новой генерации если оно получится — перегенерировать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я согласен, но вопрос стоял не про генерацию чисел.

Comment: а в чем вообще смысл добавления свойства в элемент, если хватит того, что это значение уже используется как ключ в _mapElements_?